# How do you share strings between methods and threads?

Tags: java, string, multithreading, selenium, volatile

I'm currently getting data from my clipboard in string form using one method however I need to access this information from another method running on a different thread, I've done some research and come across volatile strings but I am not quite sure how to implement them in my code, this is the basics of my code:

```
public class MobileSite {
public MobileSite(){
Thread thread = new Thread1(() -> {
         try {
             method1();
         } catch (Exception botFailed) {
              System.out.println("Bot Failed");

            }

    });

Thread thread = new Thread2(() -> {
         try {
             method2();
         } catch (Exception botFailed) {
              System.out.println("Bot Failed");

            }

    });


    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
```

method 1 gets the data and method 2 needs to use that data being in string format if anyone has any suggestions they would be much appreciated

Comment: sounds like a producer-consumer thing, have a look at e.g. [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/producer-consumer-solution-using-threads-java/). Btw shrinking the code you posted to [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) wouldn't harm.

Comment: @curiosa ill look into that had a quick scan and looks like the right sort of thing, thanks, also does that work as a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Your code example doesn't show any strings, doesn't show any "getting data from [the] clipboard", any attempt at communicating between threads. All it shows is the creation of two new threads--no clue as to what either of them does--and some rudimentary error reporting. If you expect to get any helpful answers, then you should at least show some code with comments like "post string to other thread here" and "get string from other thread here."

Comment: Also, considering that threads run independently of each other most of the time, you might want to think about how the thread that receives the string is supposed to know _when_ to receive it. Do you want it to _wait_ for the other thread to produce a string? Do you want it to periodically _check_ to see if the other thread has produced a string? Do you want it to be _interrupted_ when the other thread produces a string?  And what do you wish would happen if the producer thread wants to produce more than one string before the consumer has responded to the first one?

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer you to use StringBuilder instead of using String. Below is working example

```
    StringBuilder txt = new StringBuilder();
public void method1() {
    txt.append("String assigned");      
}

public void method2() {
    System.out.println(txt.toString());
}

public MobileSite(){
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> {
             try {
                 method1();
             } catch (Exception botFailed) {
                  System.out.println("Bot Failed");
                }
        });
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> {
             try {
                 method2();
             } catch (Exception botFailed) {
                  System.out.println("Bot Failed");
                }
        });
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
```

}

Comment: This example might not print "String assigned." It could print an empty string instead. Its a race to see whether thread2 will call `txt.toString()` before or after thread1 calls `txt.append(...)`. The main thread gives thread1 a head start, but that doesn't guarantee that thread1 will always win the race. Even if it always wins when running in one particular JVM, one particular operating system, and one particular hardware platform; the outcome could be different on some other system.

Comment: ...Actually, since the `StringBuilder` instance is accessed by different threads without any synchronization, other outcomes (e.g., a segfault) are also possible.